# Testing a branch of an existing VS Code extension branch

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm discussing with the developer of an extension in VS Code and I would like to try a pull request that is not ready yet. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do so. I went in the extension folder under .vscode/extension, I checked out to the modified branch and I used the command "yarn" because that's the package manager it used. What do I need to do to test the new work in progress?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Typically VS Code extensions developed in VS Code can just be run in the *Experimental Development Host*  just by hitting the F5 key (or Debug > Start Debugging). That is assuming you open VS Code in the context of the folder, where your extension has the `package.json` file.
If the extension has got some other manual setup required, the extension developers should describe it in a README.md file. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I try to debug, the choice are C++ debug and node.js. I think the extension uses Yarn. I guess I just have to add Yarn to my debug configuration. If I make that work, does that mean I could "use" the modified extension with different files just as if this was the live version?